# How to import other gradle?

Tags: gradle

I tried `apply from:"other.gradle"` but not work. My project had many modules, and all modules need to use some plugins like `development-manage` and `maven-publish`. So I wanna simplify the script in the `build.gradle`.

These scripts are in all modules:

```
buildscript { 
    repositories {
        maven url{ "mynexusUrl" }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.5.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
apply plugin: "maven-publish"

dependencyManagement {
   imports {
     // we publish a mavenParent pom into the nexus.
     mavenBom 'com.xxx.xxx:xx.xx:1.0-SNAPSHOT'  
   }
}

// above code is for mavenBom
// and all modules I need copy these code into the `build.gradle` file.
// bellow is for publish plugin
task sourceJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes){
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}
artifacts {
  archives jar
  archives sourceJar
}

publishing {
  // here I have many script too
}
```

As you can see, I just wanna move these script into a file and import these code just like a `import` command. So that other developer in my team can focus on what they really care.